# update two list using linq

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I want to update two lists using a LINQ query. I have an `IDictionary<>` value with ids and values. I want to update another list with relevant ids with relevant value.

```
public void UpdateList(IDictionary<int, int> sortOrder)
{
    var current = GetList();
    foreach (var item in current)
    {
        foreach (var i in sortOrder)
        {
            if (item.Id == i.Key)
            {
                item.SortOrder = i.Value;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I came up with this solution. but I need to do in more effective way using LINQ.

Comment: What is the type of `current`? *Why* do you think LINQ is a solution?

Comment: Hi Jon Skeet current is a list

Comment: A list of what? You shouldn't make us guess. (And please pay more attention to formatting and ideally spelling/grammar in future. Making a question as readable as possible makes a big difference.)

Comment: (And where does the second list come in? I can see one list and one dictionary...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well you can avoid nested loops by performing a dictionary lookup instead:

```
public void UpdateList(IDictionary<int, int> sortOrder)
{
    var current = GetList();
    foreach (var item in current)
    {
        int value;
        if (sortOrder.TryGetValue(item.Id, out value))
        {
            item.SortOrder = value;
        }
    }
}
```

That's not using LINQ, but as LINQ is for *querying* rather than *updating*, I'm not sure how LINQ would help...

Comment: really appreciate for the answer but that won't solve my issue and you answer is not acceptable. because the code i used i did condition for checking Ids of both lists because it must be in my code. thanks

Comment: @GayanRanasinghe: What do you mean by "checking ids of both lists"? You've only show one list, and one dictionary. I'm performing a lookup in the dictionary of the value in the list. Have you *tried* my answer and found it not to work? Of course, if you'd provided a short but complete program to start with, I could easily have verified that it worked...

Comment: @JonSkeet  Thanks for noting that LINQ is for querying and not updating!

Answer (score 0):

Here is LINQ Solution:

```
public void UpdateList(IDictionary<int, int> sortOrder)
{
    var current = GetList();

    current= (from c in current
       join i in sortOrder on c.Id equals i.Key into lg
       from i in lg.DefaultIfEmpty()
       select new /*Your Class Name*/{Id=c.Id, SortOrder=i==null?c.SortOrder:i.Value}).ToList(); 
}
```

Update: LEFT JOIN is better than Inner Join.

Comment: @GayanRanasinghe: *Why* do you want to do it that way though? Why do you insist on using LINQ when there's a perfectly good way of looking up an item in a dictionary? This answer doesn't modify the list, unlike your original code - it creates a *new* list... and that's if it even compiles, which seems unlikely given that it's using an anonymous type. Even if it *did* work, it would be less efficient - and considerably more complicated - than just simple iteration. LINQ isn't a golden hammer to be used on every problem.

Comment: "Update: LEFT JOIN is better than Inner Join." Better in what way? They do different things. Sometimes you want one, sometimes you want the other. This answer still doesn't update items in the existing list though, unlike the original code.

Comment: @JonSkeet I know the difference between LEFT JOIN and INNER JOIN, thanks.

Comment: So why say one is "better" with no qualification or explanation? It adds nothing to the answer.